# How do I get excel to output duration of time in hours and minutes when I input total minutes?

Tags: excel

I want Excel to output **02:18** **as time duration** if I input **138 as minutes**. I have tried custom formatting the cells with `hh:mm` but it's not working.

Comment: You can use TIME function. Assuming your 138 value is in cell A1, the formula `=TIME(0,A1,0)` will return a value that can be formatted as `hh:mm`. Formatting 138 won't work because a unit is equal to an enitire day. In fact this formula `=1/24*2+1/24/60*18` also will give you the value you are looking for. The formula takes the value equal to a day (1), divides it by 24 (hours) and multiplies it by 2 to return the 2 hours; it then sums it to the value equal to a day (1), divided by 24 (hours), divided by 60 (minutes) and multiplied by 18 to return the 2:18 hours. `=1/1440*A1` also will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **A1**, enter:

```
=TIME(0,A1,0)
```

in another.  Then format the formula cell to your requirement.

[image]